# Flask blueprint for upload of files not getting route

Tags: python, flask

Hey I am building a simple prototype in Flask and I am somehow missing something. The route to the upload is missing otherwise it's the pretty standard tutorial and I have pretty much everything working besides it's not adding the route. I have no clue why the route isn't there the debug simply gives a 404.

My routes in  **init**.py looks like this

```
@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')

from . import uploader
app.register_blueprint(uploader.bp)

from . import db
db.init_app(app)

from . import auth
app.register_blueprint(auth.bp)

return app
```

And my uploader.py looks like this

```
from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for
)
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileRequired
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flaskr.db import get_db


bp = Blueprint('uploader', __name__, url_prefix='/upload')




@bp.route('/upload', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def upload():
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        f = form.photo.data
        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        f.save(os.path.join(
            app.instance_path, 'photos', filename
        ))
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('upload.html', form=form)
```

I am probably not declaring something the right way but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wasn't in my code but on my system. I fixed this by recloning the repo I already had which was working. I have no clue what broke it.